# Target all Divs with Certain Style

Tags: jquery, html, css, selector

how can I target all divs in a page that have `margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px; and assign margin: 0,` without knowing the name of the class?

I was thinking I could do `div[style="margin-left: -15px;"][style="margin-right: -15px;"]` but that doesn't work since the styles are not applied inline.

Comment: You can use a `filter()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option is to iterate through all the elements, get margin and compare the values.

```
var allElements = $("*");
for(var e=allElements.length-1; e>=0; e--){
   var elem = allElements.eq(e);
   if(elem.css("margin-left") == "-15px"){
      //Do something
   }
}
```

Comment: update ' elem.css("margin-left") = "0;" ' with ' elem.css("margin-left", "0px") ', i've posted an updated answer with demo link

Comment: You have made two small mistakes, refer to https://jsfiddle.net/vinodkumarkv13/gh4woa47/4/

Answer (score 0):

update the script like this

**Script**

```
var allElements = $("*");
for(var e=allElements.length-1; e>=0; e--){
   var elem = allElements.eq(e);
   if(elem.css("margin-left") == "-15px"){
      //Do something
       alert("yes")
      elem.css("margin-left", "0px")
   }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh4woa47/2/)